# Split string into list, sort and maintain order

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a string that is pipe separated and I wanted to spilt it into a list and sort it in the reverse order.

But I see that the order is not maintained. Whats the problem here ?

```
String str = "Chicago|Indianapolis|Boston|Houston";
List<String> splitList= Stream.of(str.split("\\|"))
                .map(String::trim)
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .limit(30)
                .collect(toList());

//Expected [Houston,Boston,Indianapolis,Chicago]
//Got [Indianapolis,Houston,Boston,Chicago]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

Your code is that you are sorting the elements in reverse order. Thus, it maintains the reverse sorting order but not the order in which they were present in the string.

#### The Idea

The `Stream` operations you need do not store the intermediate result for you to reverse. You can iterate on the elements and keep on adding them to the beginning of the `Collection` which essentially reverses the order.

#### List vs Deque

`ArrayList`‘s `addFirst(...)` is `O(n^2)` time. So, use `Deque` instead which is efficient in adding elements to the front.

#### Code:

```java
String str = "Chicago|Indianapolis|Boston|Houston";
Deque<String> splitList = Stream.of(str.split("\\|"))
    .map(String::trim)
    .collect(Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (deq, t) -> deq.addFirst(t),
        (d1, d2) -> {
            d2.addAll(d1);
            return d2;
        }));
System.out.print(splitList);
```

#### Output:

```
[Houston, Boston, Indianapolis, Chicago]
```

---

#### Pro Tip:

In a capacity-restricted environment, you can use the method `offerFirst(...)` which will only insert the element if it does not violate the capacity restrictions. Will **need** exception handling.

Answer (score 3):

Try with below

```
    String str = "Chicago|Indianapolis|Boston|Houston";
    List<String> splitList= Arrays.asList(str.split("\\|"));
    Collections.reverse(splitList);
    System.out.println(splitList);
```

Output is:

```
[Houston, Boston, Indianapolis, Chicago]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to do that

```
String cityStr = "Chicago|Indianapolis|Boston|Houston";
List<String> cityList = Arrays.asList(cityStr.split("\\|"))
.stream().sorted( Comparator.reverseOrder()).collect( Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No it use the Collections.reverseOrder(). But I used Comparator.reverseOrder(). That should work properly. Trim is not mandatory for the given String